# How to bind named parameters with PDO data-type

Tags: php, pdo

Im using PDO in PHP and I need to know how to bind my named parameters to a PDO data-type since PDO just reads my parameter as a string value in default when i need it to be an integer.
This is my code

```
    $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(':limit'=>$limit, ':offset'=>$offset);
```

Comment: Does the string not function the same way?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php.

Comment: offset and limit doesn't read strings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info